# Toggling between components on a click in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component which acts as the front of my single page site.

I have the following within that:

```
<div className="flex mb-0 items-center">
        <h2 className="capitalize tracking-tight text-4xl mt-16 mr-8 md:mt-24 font-black hvr-underline-from-left pb-1">
          recent projects
        </h2>
        <h2 className="capitalize tracking-tight text-4xl mt-16 md:mt-24 font-black text-gray-400 hvr-underline-from-left pb-1">
          open source
        </h2>
      </div>
      <Projects />
      <OpenSource />
```

Currently I have the components displaying underneath each other. I want to be able to Toggle between the two, if a user clicks "recent projects" it shows the `<Projects />` component. If a users clicks "open source" it hides the `<Projects />` component and displays the `<OpenSource/>` one.

I would love to create an animation like a slide with something like react spring. But happy to just have them toggling at the moment.

any advice?

Comment: What's the name of the UI framework that you are using now?

Comment: I’m building this in Gatsby. And not using any libraries for animation or anything yet. I have React-Spring installed but not using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [activeComponent, setActiveComponent] = useState("projects");

  const modifyActiveComponent = useCallback(
    newActiveComponent => {
      setActiveComponent(newActiveComponent);
    },
    [setActiveComponent]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex mb-0 items-center">
        <h2
          onClick={() => modifyActiveComponent("projects")}
          className="capitalize tracking-tight text-4xl mt-16 mr-8 md:mt-24 font-black hvr-underline-from-left pb-1"
        >
          recent projects
        </h2>
        <h2
          onClick={() => modifyActiveComponent("open_source")}
          className="capitalize tracking-tight text-4xl mt-16 md:mt-24 font-black text-gray-400 hvr-underline-from-left pb-1"
        >
          open source
        </h2>
      </div>
      {activeComponent === "projects" && <h1>Projects</h1>}
      {activeComponent === "open_source" && <h1>OpenSource</h1>}
    </>
  );
}
```

Above I created a simple example to toggle two components. I used the `useState` hook to save the active component. I added the `useCallback` hook to code as well to handle the click on an item and update the active component afterwards.

You can play demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-carson-jghdi?file=/src/App.js:0-1042

Comment: Awesome!! This works perfectly...now to animate it.. thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

I made this example with react transition group: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-curie-nq3wo?file=/src/App.js

There you can see the animation effect, you can define of each transition and a lot of funny stuff.
(I did a small trick in the `.section-exit` to be able to show a smooth transition, which is the `position: absolute` without overlapping sections.

**Documentation:** https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group

**JS:** https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-curie-nq3wo?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const sections = ["PROJECTS", "OPENSOURCE"];
  const [activeSection, setActiveSection] = useState(sections[0]);

  const setProject = () => setActiveSection(sections[0]);
  const setOpenSource = () => setActiveSection(sections[1]);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setProject}>Project</button>
      <button onClick={setOpenSource}>Open Source</button>
      <CSSTransition
        classNames="section"
        in={activeSection === sections[0]}
        timeout={300}
        unmountOnExit
      >
        <h1>Projects</h1>
      </CSSTransition>
      <CSSTransition
        classNames="section"
        in={activeSection === sections[1]}
        timeout={300}
        unmountOnExit
      >
        <h1>Open Source</h1>
      </CSSTransition>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**CSS:** https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-curie-nq3wo?file=/src/styles.css

```
.section-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.section-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
}

.section-exit {
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.section-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: opacity 300, transform 300;
}
```

There you can see the effect.